# Objective-C: Is a class just a .m and .h file?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, class

I'm still coming to terms with classes and objects in Objective-C.

Is a class simply the combination of an interface and implementation file? Or, to put it another way, when would you say to yourself "I need a new .m file for this". At the moment I make a new implementation file when I want to put certain methods and variables in a separate place so that my main code doesn't become massive.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Strictly by convention and not by necessity, every new class should have an interface file (.h file) and an implementation file (.m file).

As far as using new .m files for distributing your methods, this is fine.

Comment: +1 Yes, and in case it's not totally clear from this answer, unless you have a reason for doing otherwise (which if you're just starting out you won't), create a new .m/.h pair for every new class.

Comment: @achiral: you can split class interface definition, too - using categories. Look 'em up if you wish.

Answer (score 2):

While convention dictates a pair of .h and .m files per class, the former containing the @interface and the latter containing the @implementation, there is no such requirement and, in fact, many of the system provided classes are divided across several files both in interface and implementation.

Technically, you don't need an `@interface` at all.

The absolute minimal class definition is:

```
@implementation Foo
@end
```

In that the above defines a class `Foo` that is a new root class.   However, the compiler will warn about this.

Effectively, the minimal class definition is:

```
@interface Foo:NSObject
@end
@implementation Foo
@end
```

Note that `NSObject` is intentional;  if you are going to make a class that will be compatible with the system frameworks or, even, the system runtime, inheriting from NSObject is pretty much required.

Syntactically, it is up to you as to how you separate the `@interface` and the `@implementation`.   Traditionally, the interface goes in a header file such that others might #import it and use it while the implementation goes into a compilation unit -- a .m file -- to be compiled and linked exactly once.

But that is convention, not requirement.   I've often defined a class --- @interface + @implementation -- entirely in a single .m file solely for use within the @implementation of some other class;   effectively, a private class.

Note that class extensions -- `@interface Foo()` -- were expressly created to allow you to declare additional properties and methods on a class outside of the .h file's `@interface Foo:NSObject`.  It allows a class to effectively have hidden API or to create a property that is publicly readonly and privately read-write.

Answer (score 1):

No it's not. You can place multiple classes in a .h and .m file, althought this isn't deemed good practice.

Answer (score 0):

In Objective-C classes are a pair of interfaces and implementations. These don't have to be in separate files but often are and it is a good way to keep your file structure clean.  Often classes represent a little factory and when you have a group of functions that can be grouped together it is a good idea to put them in a class together.

Answer (score 0):

I'll admit to occasionally grouping a few classes together, either with the definitions of all in one .h and the implementations in one .m, or, where some classes are "private", with the definitions AND implementations of "inner" classes in the .m of the major class.

I think it's sometimes good to avoid a proliferation of files this way, and to group interdependent classes together.

You can also go the other way -- spread the definition and and/or implementation of a class among multiple files using "categories" -- but that's a touch ugly and should generally be reserved for extending frameworks classes with specialized functions.  (And even at that, done with some apprehension.)